# Access the site from multiple computers on a home network with IIS

Tags: iis

We have a VS project in this location:**C:\inetpub\wwwroot:**
[project in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP3MF.png)

this project run perfectly,
we uploaded the IIS and it is run perfectly in the local computer that contain the IIS inside.

then we took the computer name and from another computer, in the same local network, we tried to put in the address line, on the browser, the name of the computer that the IIS is installed there and I got this error:
This site can’t be reached
laptop-******** took too long to respond.

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGJqX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check these options:

1. If there is running firewall on the computer, where IIS is running, make an inbound rule for your port (in your case 11111).
2. On client PC, access IIS with "computer-name:port/webpage.html" (in your case "laptop-g3j5vgcc:11111/panel/login.html") .

You may also change the port of your web site (if you want to use port different from 11111).

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Select your website and choose "Bindings ...".
3. Change port and confirm.
4. Restart your web site.